# X-AppEngine-CityLatLong not populated on Google App Engine Django 1.5.11 when using WSGIRequest

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm not getting the X-AppEngine-CityLatLong (or City or Country) values back in the POST header when I submit a POST to my WSGI Django 1.5.11 Python app on Google App Engine.

My wsgi.py is typical:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

from which I get a request object via my urls.py the normal way. My request attributes such as request.method, etc. are all populated correctly. However, when I look for the GAE-injected headers to lookup the geolocation of the client:

```
@staticmethod
def get_demographics(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        slatlong = request.GET.get("X-AppEngine-CityLatLong")
        lat = slatlong.split(",")[0]
        lng = slatlong.split(",")[1]
        city = request.GET.get("X-AppEngine-City")
        country = request.GET.get("X-AppEngine-Country")
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        slatlong = request.POST.get("X-AppEngine-CityLatLong")
        lat = slatlong.split(",")[0]
        lng = slatlong.split(",")[1]
        city = request.POST.get("X-AppEngine-City")
        country = request.POST.get("X-AppEngine-Country")
    else:
        lat = 0
        lng = 0
        city = 'unknown'
        country = 'unknown'
    return ip, lat, lng, city, country
```

each of the request.POST.gets, for example:

```
request.POST.get("X-AppEngine-CityLatLong")
```

returns a NoneType, instead of (in the case of CityLatLong) the expected comma-delimited string (e.g. "1.234,-5.678"). This causes the subsequent string split meant to separate the lat/long to throw a HTTP 500 with:

> "NoneType" object has no attribute "split"

Some code examples on StackOverflow say to use request.getHeader for this, but when I do that I get a HTTP 500 with:

> "WSGIRequest" object has no attribute "getHeader"

Any solution much appreciated.

More info on the X-AppEngine headers: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Request_headers

Comment: `META` contains http headers. Did you mean `request.META.get()`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the previous version I attempted had request.META.get instead of request.POST.get. It had the same exact problem: failing on the split because it too returns a NoneType.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: FIXED**

The actual calls to use are:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITYLATLONG')
request.META.get('HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITY')
request.META.get('HTTP_X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY')
request.META.get('HTTP_X_APPENGINE_REGION')
```